# How can I easily cd into a flash drive from cli?

Tags: command-line, directory, usb-drive

Right now I am accessing all of my files from my native directories. However, I want to also use a flash drive for extra storage. In that case, what would my terminal command be to access my flash drive (for this example, assume flash drive name is "MYDRIVE")

Thank you!

Comment: Drag file from nautilus to terminal it should put '/path/to/file'

Comment: So there is not just a simple syntax I type into the terminal which allows me to move from my hard drive storage to a flash drive?

Comment: With a bit of fantasy there is, see update...

Comment: Hi dhaneku.b, could you indicate if you found what you were looking for in (either) one of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

It depends, but you can easily find out...

#### From GUI

...by right-clicking on *any* of the files or folders inside the drive, and choose > Properties ("Eigenschappen" in Dutch), in nautilus:

[image]

As you can see, the directory is

```
/media/jacob/My Passport
```

Note that in commands, you need to fix the (possible) space:

```
/media/jacob/'My Passport'
```

#### From cli

run:

```
lsblk | grep '<drive_name>' | awk -F'part '  '{ print $2 }'
```

example:

```
$ lsblk | grep 'My Passport' | awk -F'part ' '{ print $2 }'
```

outputs:

```
/media/jacob/My Passport
```

Again, note that in commands, you need to fix the (possible) space.

#### CD to the directory in one step

```
cd "$(lsblk | grep '<drive_name>' | awk -F'part ' '{ print $2 }')"
```

Where `<drive_name>` (of course) is the name of your drive.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out where your flash drive is mounted, you can use the command `lsblk`.  Example output:

```
theone@jakku:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   753M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   139G  0 part /media/theone/EE4601124600DD69
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  93.1G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0  64.7M  0 loop /snap/ubuntu-core/109
loop1    7:1    0   6.3M  0 loop /snap/hangups/1
```

As you can see, it lists all attached devices and their mount points. Then, all you would have to do is `cd /your/flash/mountpoint`. For example, if I wanted to access my Windows partition for some reason, I could do `cd /media/theone/EE4601124600DD69`. If your flash drive is listed, but not mounted, you can also do `mount -o gid=1000,uid=1000 /dev/sdXY /media/user/mountpoint` where `X` is is the dev letter (`sda`, `sdb`, etc) and `Y` is the partition number.

If you're coming from Windows, you might be used to old structure of each disk being assigned a "drive". However, everything is a file in Linux. Therefore, even external storage devices can be accessed as "files" stemming down from the root directory.

Comment: So let's say I usually access my documents as such

`$ cd ./Documents`

Would I have to do a lot of stuff differently in order to access my documents folder from my flash drive?

Comment: You can do `cd ~/Documents`. The `~` character expands to your home directory when interpreted.

Answer (score -1):

Physical disks are named by sd(a,b,c,...) 
sd = Sata disk
a = first disk 
b = second disk
etc...
I hope you understood up to here now you should know which one is your harddisk
after that you should mount your Disk if it is not mounted automatically if it is mounted you can find it's mount point by type "df -h" in output search for mountpoint column of your disk you can access or cd to your Disk from it's mount point if it is not mounted you can mount it manually for mounting a disk you should:
first create a directory to mount you disk into that for example I create it on my desktop named as mount
then mount your disk in to that by 
sudo mount /dev/sd.. /home/UserName/Desktop/mount
first dot (.) is for your hard disk specification and second dot is for specifying your file system or partition.